# Flink watermark: the frequency of sending watermark by implementing the WatermarkGenerator

Tags: apache-flink

I saw the below example in official guidance.

```
public class BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator implements WatermarkGenerator<MyEvent> {

    private final long maxOutOfOrderness = 3500; 

    private long currentMaxTimestamp;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event, long eventTimestamp, WatermarkOutput output) {
        currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(currentMaxTimestamp, eventTimestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeriodicEmit(WatermarkOutput output) {
        
        output.emitWatermark(new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness - 1));
    }

}
```

The allowed maximum lateness is 3.5 seconds. Does it mean that this will send a watermark per 3.5 seconds? If not, I do not understand what the point of timestamp comparison in `onEvent` implementation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onEvent` method of the `BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator` is tracking the largest timestamp seen so far in the stream. Based on the assumption that the stream is at most `maxOutOfOrderness` out of order, having seen a timestamp with a value of `currentMaxTimestamp`, we assume that all events with a timestamp less than `currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness - 1` should have arrived by now.

`onPeriodicEmit` is called every `autoWatermarkInterval` milliseconds, which by default is 200 msec.

`Math.max` is ensuring that `currentMaxTimestamp` does not go backwards.